# Google URL Shortner API Setting Service Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the Google URL Shortner API, https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#URL_Shortener_API, and need to set the quotaUser parameter.  This should be do-able via the service.ServiceParameters dictionary and quotaUser is already a key in the dictionary, but it's read only so I can't set the value of quotaUser to what I need it to be.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  I don't see why they would provide the dictionary but then no way to set the values in it.

Answer (score 1):

Each service request contains QuotaUser property, so you can set as you want. 
For example look in following sample code:

```
var service = new UrlshortenerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = auth,
                ApplicationName = "PUT_HERE_YOUR_APP_NAME",
            });
// some code here...
// create the request set its quota and execute
var request = service.Url.List();
request.QuotaUser = "PUT_HERE_YOUR_QUOTA"
UrlHistory result = request.Execute();
```

Take a look in our UrlshortenerService sample [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/UrlShortener.ListURLs/Program.cs?repo=samples) for full sample for how to use Urlshortener service (I added the QuotaUser property after line 72)